# calculating a point in python vs st_project

Tags: python, geolocation, postgis

As you can see i'm trying to implement the function st_project in python. However, I don't get the same result as with the function st_project

```
import geopy as g 
import geopy.distance as gp 
from geopy.units import radians

start = g.Point(27.725778916300465,35.201911926269524)
distance = g.distance.VincentyDistance(meters = 50)
result = distance.destination(start, radians(90))
```

The output: `Point(27.72574882153389, 35.29318076870505, 0.0)`

However, when a execute the st_project i get the following

```
SELECT ST_AsText (
    ST_PROJECT(
        (SELECT SET_SetSRID(
            ST_POINT(27.725778916300465,35.201911926269524),
            4326)),
        50,
        radians(90)
    )
);
```

The output: `Point(27.7263279818659 35.2019119250247)`

Any idea to get the exact result ?

Comment: I guess the issue here is rather regarding the level of precision of your coordinates. What are you mapping with these coordinates? Just to make my point clear, at the 9th decimal number you're already by `microns`, which is a pretty small unity of measurement ;-) If you're ok with meters, 5 decimal places are ok.

Comment: It seems your projection is 90 degrees off from the other result. But I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `ST_Point` expects the "x-coordinate" as its first argument, i.e., longitude (assuming `EPSG 4326`), while the `Point` constructor of `geopy` takes as its first argument the latitude. Also, the `destination` method [expects](https://github.com/geopy/geopy/blob/1.10.0/geopy/distance.py#L439) the bearing in degrees (in contrast to `ST_Project` which expects radians).

Thus if you do instead:

```
SELECT ST_AsText (
    ST_PROJECT(
        (SELECT ST_SetSRID(
            ST_POINT(35.201911926269524,27.725778916300465),
            4326)),
        50,
        radians(90.0)
    )
);
```

you get:

```
                st_astext
------------------------------------------
 POINT(35.2024189755536 27.7257789153716)
(1 row)
```

and with:

```
import geopy as g 
import geopy.distance as gp 
from geopy.units import radians

start = g.Point(27.725778916300465,35.201911926269524)
distance = g.distance.VincentyDistance(meters = 50)

result = distance.destination(start, 90) #no radians here
print(result.longitude, result.latitude)
```

you get a consistent result:

```
35.202418975487014 27.725778915371617
```